# Unable to use Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync when signed into a shared mailbox on Outlook on the Web

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

To reproduce the same, you will require an add-in which works in the `MessageCompose` interface. I was unable to install Script Lab in the Shared Mailbox environment; if you face the same problem, you may need to create a simple add-in that uses the `Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync` API.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Login to Outlook on the Web.
2. Click on your profile on the top-right corner of the screen.
3. Choose `Open another mailbox`
4. Type and select a shared mailbox which you have access to.
5. Once you are loaded into the shared mailbox, compose a new message and open the add-in.
6. The attachment upload progress bar gets stuck. As a result, even the callback provided to `addFileAttachmentAsync` will never be called.

Comment: Are you able to attach same file using addFileAttachmentAsync in user mailbox? There are some limitations to this API. Please check this link for more details- https://review.learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/limits-for-activation-and-javascript-api-for-outlook-add-ins?branch=master#limits-for-javascript-api

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Yes I am able to attach the same file using the same URI with addFileAttachmentAsync in user mailbox. Also, I am unable to access the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

"Open another Mailbox" add-in scenarios are not fully supported on Outlook Web and the support is currently in our backlog. The feature is currently in preview for Win32. ( link to document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows#shared-mailboxes-preview). We will update our documentation to reflect this state. Thanks for your patience